# Codeigniter mysql insert query stripping string

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, xss

### Added Example Code

Please read below for full details, this is an example function that can be put in a controller which generates the same results. The database structure is posted further down:

```
public function test()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['comment_original']))
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $comment_original = $this->form_validation->xss_clean(html_escape($_POST['comment_original']));

            var_dump($comment_original);

            $this->db->insert('comments', array(
                'comment_set_id'        =>  2993,
                'comment_user_id'       =>  40,
                'comment_original'      =>  $comment_original,
                'comment_enabled'       =>  1,
                'comment_is_spam'       =>  0,
                'comment_time_added'    =>  1358090826,
                'comment_time_updated'  =>  1358090826
            ));

            var_dump($this->db->last_query());
        }

        $this->output->set_output('<form method="post">
            <textarea name="comment_original"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>');
    }
```

### The original problem

Hey guys when I try and insert a string like this into my database, into a TEXT column.

> http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

It winds up in the database as:

> http://img.chronofoot.com/

I've done $this->db->last_query() to show what query Codeigniter is running and it returns this:

```
INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment_set_id`, `comment_user_id`, `comment_original`, `comment_html`, `comment_enabled`, `comment_is_spam`, `comment_time_added`, `comment_time_updated`, `comment_ip_address`) VALUES (2993, 40, 'http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg', 'http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg', 1, 0, 1358090826, 1358090826, 'XXX')
```

So it would seem it isn't being stripped out before it tries to do the insert. Putting that exact string into php my admin inserts just fine with the full string.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

### Extra Information

It will strip anything after the "é" so the same thing will happen to a string like this:

> http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg This is extra dummy text

The string being posted in the form is actually this:

> http://img.chronofoot.com/%E9ric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

But xss_clean converts %E9 to é which isn't actually what I want, but i'm tentative to to do anything to the core xxs_clean function.

On a final note, this is what my table looks like, although I don't think that makes any difference:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_set_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_user_id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_original` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_html` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_attachments` text,
  `comment_time_added` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_time_updated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_is_spam` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_has_attachments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_has_edits` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_ip_address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Updated Question: Escaping HTML

Just thought i'd some extra information.

So like I said the actual string being posted is this:

> http://img.chronofoot.com/%E9ric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

This goes through html_escape and then xss_clean. If I put it through xss_clean first then it returns an empty string

```
var_dump($this->form_validation->xss_clean(html_escape($_POST['comment_original'])))
//Returns http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg
```

And xss_clean first

```
var_dump(html_escape($this->form_validation->xss_clean($_POST['comment_original'])))
//Returns ''
```

htmlentities will solve it in a way, in that it will convert the string to this:

> http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

But this form is just adding a comment, so any amount of text could be added and htmlentities so if something like this is posted:

> This won't work http://img.chronofoot.com/%E9ric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

html_escape() would convert it to this

> This won't work http://img.chronofoot.com/%E9ric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

xss_clean() then converts it to this

> This won't work http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

And then htmlentities() would convert it to this:

> This won&#039;t work http://img.chronofoot.com/éric-di-meco/interview-eric-di-meco_66454_w250.jpg

This would of course destroy the word "won't" as the ampersand would be converted twice.

Comment: show us the code please.

Comment: Well it goes through various models, but i'll knock up some pseudo code

Comment: just add the query building steps.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan i've added an example function that can be put in a CI controller

Comment: try the solution I provided. it might help you. :)

Comment: This is why you do XSS/HTML filtering before you output to the user, not before inserting into the database. See [here for a good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3648438/271402).

Answer (score 0):

You should just URL encode using `urlencode()` when inserting data into your table, and use `urldecode()` after selecting the data.

It's much cleaner, and you don't hae to worry about special characters.

Comment: urlencode and urldecode are only relevant for links though? I don't think it'd be a good idea to urlencode and decode entire lumps of text. I guess I didn't make it clear, i'm not trying to insert just a url, it's just that when a comment is posted that contains that URL it breaks and strips the rest of the comment/string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array =  array(
                'comment_set_id'        =>  2993,
                'comment_user_id'       =>  40,
                'comment_enabled'       =>  1,
                'comment_is_spam'       =>  0,
                'comment_time_added'    =>  1358090826,
                'comment_time_updated'  =>  1358090826
            );
$this->db->set('comment_original',$comment_original,FALSE);
$this->db->set($array);
$this->db->insert('comments');
```

Comment: Will this definitely prevent any sql injection though? Seeing as it's a form, that needs to be considered and I don't think it will be properly protected this way.

Comment: first of all. is it working. second, as long as you are fixing the xss before submitting with the proper conditions, then yes, no sql injection will be problem :)

Comment: I think you're mistaken. xss protection is not to protect against sql exploits, it's for cross site scripting like injecting unwanted javascript or html into the page. This method would require adding strings "'" around $comment_original, which could easily be closed within the posted form.

Comment: you may do many types of xss, even you can do our own one. but have you tried my code? if it's working I can help you with sql injection problem then. but for the mean time is it ok with you?

Comment: Well yes of course it works. But I don't think this is the right route. This is just one example of one user who had a problem with posting one link. To ensure this doesn't happen again, every form and every mysql insert will need to be changed to not use CI's built in sql protection, which will basically involve recoding the entire site or recoding codeigniter to use an alternative way to prevent sql exploits.

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop - go to php chat room to talk about it :)

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop : wait , are you saying that CI has actually some magical *"sql protection"* to begin with??!

Comment: @Freeze Dried Pop CI handles protection against SQL injection automatically, doing it again will only cause you more problems. And in any case, you aren't doing anything to prevent SQL injection anyway, you're only cleaning the string of HTML and other characters that the person could use to inject HTML/JS. XSS is not the same as SQL injection. You're having problems because you're doing XSS filtering before inserting instead of before showing the output to the user.

Comment: @vanneto I was responding to the proposed solution where FALSE is sent to the set() function which is telling CI not to automatically escape. I am well aware that I am not doing any sql injection protection myself, what i'm saying is, is that this suggestion unacceptable on the basis that it takes away the sql injection that CI handles automatically.

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop I understand. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Still, filtering like this should be done before sending content to the user, not before inserting.

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop - one more thing, when you pass this string you should expect sql injection. and that's why CI handles it not to be passed as you expected. but still you want to pass it. then this is a solution for it, regardless to the injection part. which is not mentioned by you in your question. otherwise, you could strip the string manually and add it to multiple DB columns.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan fair enough, but I didn't think protection against sql injection would need to be specified. I'm starting to think the problem is in the xss_clean function. As it turns a valid url into a url non valid url.

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop - vaneto added a link for you to see XSS check it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using $_POST over $this->input->post()? Then you can use form validation rules with xss_clean.

Comment: That would just run through the same function so what's the difference? I only used this example to show that you get different results when running xss_clean first or html_escape first.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting that url with htmlentities before you pass it to the database.

```
$comment_html = htmlentities($string);
```

Also, make sure you var_dump (not echo) that $this->db->last_query().  Special characters will output differently.

```
var_dump($this->db->last_query());
```

Comment: It already goes through html_escape() so htmlentities would cause &#039; to turn into &amp;#039;