# How to remove HTML-Tags in the database?

Tags: php, html, database

If I insert something into my databse it inserts the html tags with it. How can i prevent this ?

```
public function selectFromDatabase ()
{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM gb ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 4";
    //data output
    if ( $result = $this->mysqli->query($query) )
    {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() )
        {
            echo strip_tags( $row->titel . "\t" . $row->autor . " (" . $row->email . ") schrieb am <br>" . $row->datum . "<br><br>" .$row->text , '<br>');
            echo "<hr>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

I am using strip_tags already. It shows me perfectly without the tags but not in my database.

This is my code to insert the value.

```
    public function insertToDatabase()
{
    //Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO gb (titel,autor, email, text, datum) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    if ( $this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
    {
        //Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $this->stmt->bind_param("sssss", $this->gen,$this->name, $this->mail, $this->nachricht, $this->datum);
        //Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if ( $this->stmt->execute() )
        {
            echo "Hier ist dein Kommentar \u{261F} <br><br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . $this->mysqli->error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
    $this->stmt->close();
}
```

This is how it looks like in my database

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the tags before executing the query ? str_replace or another function since you already what tag you should be removing

Comment: What is wrong with HTML in your database?

Comment: You can use [strip_tags()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

Comment: @Ivar Vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: @Daidara11 You never used strip_tags() while inserting?

Comment: @vivek_23 Not if it is resting in the database and if you escape it properly before you render it in your HTML.

Comment: @vivek_23 oh .. no not while inserting just when i have to display it.

Comment: @Ivar ok, but why store and escape when you don't need them in your application(as far as OP's concern goes)? Also, I would rather like to store them escaped or htmlentitied to be on safer side.

Comment: @vivek_23 What if at some point you don't want to render it as HTML, [but as plaintext or JSON instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648430/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-escape-html-before-inserting-into-a-database-instead-of-upon)?

Comment: @vivek_23 
Because this is a task from my university prof and I have to do it :S

Comment: @Ivar Well, we do have methods(at least in PHP) to decode them back to original format such as [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and [htmlspecialchars_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). The reason why I prefer escaping before inserting is because sometimes we use PHP HTML based tools such as Phpmyadmin for MySQL data and I am afraid if inserted HTML could perform anything malicious.

Comment: @Daidara11 You are not stripping tags while inserting in the database in your insert query, so obviously they will be present.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thank you for the information ! So where should I add the strip_tag() in my code ? I add it after my $sql but I think that is not the solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `strip_tags` when inserting in the DB table. Then you **won't need** it while displaying. To do so, change your insert line

```
 $this->stmt->bind_param("sssss", $this->gen,$this->name, $this->mail, $this->nachricht, $this->datum);
```

to

```
list($this->gen,$this->name, $this->mail, $this->nachricht, $this->datum) = array_map("strip_tags",[$this->gen,$this->name, $this->mail, $this->nachricht, $this->datum]);

$this->stmt->bind_param("sssss", $this->gen,$this->name, $this->mail, $this->nachricht, $this->datum);
```